# How to get an apk with app signing key by Google Play Store?

Tags: android, apk, android-app-signing

I need to get an APK with app signing key by Google Play Store to upload on my CDN so that it has the same key and successfully get updated.

I tried with (apk+upload key) but it seems it's not the same as the apk after being uploaded to the play store(apk+app signing key). So, even though I upload (apk+upload key) to my CDN, users can't update after downloading the (apk+upload key) because they have (apk+app signing key). It says `it's not installed`.

Is there any solution?

Answer (score 3):

The Artifact library in the Play Console allows you to download APKs signed with the app signing key.

Go to "Release management > Artifact library", then when clicking on the download icon, it will open a window with the ability to download the APK signed with the app signing key; it's called "Derived APK".

Comment: Is it exactly the same apk with the application on Play Store? but I uploaded aab, not apk there.

Comment: Then you should have an "Explore" button in the Artifact Library which will take you to the Bundle Explorer allowing you to download APKs generated for all devices that your app supports.

Comment: It shows a lot of APKs. But I need one APK that covers all the devices.

Comment: It's called a universal APK. It's unfortunately not something that the Play Console generates today. [Bundletool](https://developer.android.com/studio/command-line/bundletool) allows you to generate a universal APK locally, but it won't be signed with the app signing key if you don't have it.

Answer (score 2):

As mentioned in the comments of [Pierre's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59858703/2414033), what you need is a **universal APK** and it's now available in the assets of your *"App bundle explorer"*.[image: universal APK]